# Given the dendrogram, is this an anomaly?

Tags: scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I used Scipy to create the following dendrogram:

[image]

I used the Levenshtein distance to create a distance matrix with `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`, which I then used for clustering using `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.ward`. This was the output I got after I used `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram`.

The sample of words I used is:

> ```
>        'bistum osnabrück intranet', 'fernbusse kaiserslautern',
>        'abfalleimer gelber sack', 'crazy factory app', 'angel schwerin',
>        'mietspiegel oberstaufen', 'sata jet nr 95',
>        'haare schneiden schere', 'magix deluxe 2013', 'coach bus',
>        'zwergobst', '+ischia +sorriso', '+sägeblatt +schärfdienst',
>        '+av +receiver +onkyo +tx +nr646', 'treppenbau aachen',
>        'ivb nummer', 'elektro hoen saarlouis', 'disponent ausbildung',
>        '+schokolade +werkzeug', 'bildungsurlaub englisch',
>        'deutsche lernen b1', 'mietewohnung', 'anwendung von roundup',
>        'rente nachzahlung', 'klinik am zauberwald',
>        'beton schutting prijzen', '+vergewaltigung +afrikaner',
>        'sandstein bremen', 'straubing landshuter hof',
>        'brandenburgviewer', 'gebetskleidung frauen', 'keepass 2 deutsch',
>        'emp versand', 'einrichtungshaus münchen',
>        '+bmw +dachgepäckträger +e91', 'blokker gartenmöbel',
>        'konto sparkasse kosten', 'navis fürs fahrrad',
>        '+buffalo +steakhaus', 'autogalerie köhler siegen',
>        'rennie nebenwirkungen', 'geräte schutzbrief',
>        'sozialberatung leipzig', 'bomann gspe 649 anleitung',
>        'klimaschutz bilder', 'maggi zwiebelsuppe',
>        'zitat für hochzeitskarte', 'kreul schablonen'
> ```

Why are `4` (*abfalleimer gelber sack*), `37` (*blokker gartenmöbel*), `41` (*autogalerie köhler siegen*), `44` (*sozialberatung leipzig*) omitted?

Comment: What if the color of the cluster is just black?

Comment: you are right, is indeed `black`. please submit the answer so that I can mark it as answered. ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if the color of the cluster is just black?